# Blender fails to launch - Floating Point Exception (Core Dumped)

Tags: arch-linux, core-dump, floating-point, gvfs, blender

I am new to Linux so excuse my noob. I haven't been able to find an answer for this anywhere nor have I even found anyone with a similar problem and no one on discord has an answer either.. I am running Arch with DWM and Kittie. I have installed the py and alsa packages.

When I run Blender from dmenu nothing happens. Running it in terminal launches blender for a second with a blank or bugged out screen before crashing and returning:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/ non-existent directory
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

I tried running the command "sudo blender":

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

I made the gvfs directory from the command line, reinstalled Asla and rebooted and now I just get the Floating point exception both ways.

Any ideas?

Note: every time I reboot for anything the gvfs file disappears.. this is a genome file dir if I'm not mistaken so I'm even more confused now.

Update : I attempted to remove, install Steam and install Blender through stam and it still fails with the folowing error

```
Exiting app 365670
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/ non-existent directory
```

You don't appear to have gvfs installed. What distribution are you on? You'll likely need to install gvfs through your package manager.

Comment: Thanks hadet. I tried it yesterday and it was saying the package didn't exist, but I see it on the arch wiki so I will try again toay.

Comment: I don't know why it was returning "target not found" yesterday, but it also wasn't willing to uninstall rxvt-unicode either.. but, it did install and that fixed the recurring gvfs error I was having. The "Floating point exception (core dumped)" error is still very present.